# How to solve the "EOF within quoted string" in a web scraping function?

Tags: r, web-scraping

So I'm using this web scraping function `boldseqspec` which returns data on specimens of several species based on a vector of taxonomic groups given in the "taxon" argument like this:

```
df<-bold_seqspec(taxon=c("group1","group2","group3"), format = "tsv")
```

But recently for some cases I'm getting the following message and subsequently losing information when I use it:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

I've gotten this before in read.delim but I solved it with this:

```
df<-read.delim("file.txt",quote = "",comment.char = "")
```

Reproducible example:

```
install.packages("bold")
library(bold)
df<-bold_seqspec(taxon=c("Cnidaria","Hippocampus"), format = "tsv", marker="COI-5P")
```

The problem is that the function I'm using for data mining (`boldseqspec`) doesn't have the quote and comment.char arguments.

Comment: The reproducible examples throw no errors for me

Comment: I'm sorry, I've now corrected it and it should output the error

Comment: I tried to run your example. It gives me the warning you also mention, but it yields the result.

Comment: Yes it outputs the result but with a data set much smaller than what it was supposed to be if it didn't give out the warning. Similar to when I get the warning with the "read.delim" function, the data set is always smaller and I'm losing data

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the tsv output contains both double-quotes and single quotes and this is why the parsing mucks up (for more information on the matter - actually it is also about a biological data set, too - see [EOF-within-quoted-string / difference between read.delim() and read.table()](https://kbroman.org/blog/2017/08/08/eof-within-quoted-string/))

Hence, if you can't set quotations, I'd suggest using a workaround by setting the `format = "xml"` and convert the xml to a DataFrame in a further step with the libraries `XML` (or `xml2`?) and `dplyr`.

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr) 
xml = bold_seqspec(taxon=c("Cnidaria","Hippocampus"), format = "xml", marker="COI-5P")
df= xmlToDataFrame(xml , stringsAsFactors = FALSE,) %>% 
                        mutate_all(~type.convert(., as.is = T))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the first line works perfectly with not error, but running the second one returns the following error:
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘xmlToDataFrame’ for signature ‘"xml_document", "missing", "missing", "missing", "missing"’